# How to show GTK+ dialog in front of OpenGL

Tags: opengl, dialog, modal-dialog, gtk, glfw

I've been working on creating a simple [cross-platform message box / dialog library](https://github.com/aaronmjacobs/Boxer). I decided to make it as I am currently using GLFW for windowing, which unfortunately does not provide dialog creation support.

As far as dialog creation goes on its own, my library works fine. However, when I use it along with GLFW on Linux, I have some issues with ordering. The dialog (which is modal) will appear on top of the frame of my GLFW window, but the actual contents of my GLFW window (being drawn to with OpenGL) are drawn in front of the dialog, like so:

[image: dialog]

My Linux implementation looks like this:

```
#include <boxer/boxer.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

namespace boxer {

void show(const char *message, const char *title) {
  gtk_init(0, NULL);

  GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(NULL,
            GTK_DIALOG_MODAL,
            GTK_MESSAGE_INFO,
            GTK_BUTTONS_OK,
            "%s",
            message);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(dialog), title);
  gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));

  gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(dialog));
  while (g_main_context_iteration(NULL, false));
}

} // namespace boxer
```

Is it possible to force the GTK+ dialog to be drawn in front of the contents of my GLFW window?

Answer (score 0):

I was using a virtual machine to test the creation of dialogs on Linux - as it turns out some of the virtual machine settings were causing OpenGL to act a bit strange. Tinkering with the virtual machine settings fixed the issue.

Specifically, I was running Ubuntu 12.04 in VirtualBox on OS X, and I had to disable 3D acceleration in order to fix the problem.

Comment: Which virtual machine were you using and how did you fix the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I've updated my answer to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks! I've been searching for a way to tinker with VirtualBox to get OpenGL to work properly with acceleration, and I had a momentary flash of hope that you'd found one.